# Combine multiple ARM templates

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-rm-template

I have two different ARM templates which creates two different Resource Groups and corresponding .ps1 files . I want to combine both the templates into one ARM template and deploy the resource groups from a single .ps1 file .
How can i achieve this scenario?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [cross-resource group deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-cross-resource-group-deployment).

Use this snippet inside template to deploy to another resource group:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "name": "nestedTemplate",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "resourceGroup": "crossResourceGroupDeployment",
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {},
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                    "name": "[parameters('StorageAccountName2')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
                    "location": "West US",
                    "properties": {
                        "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "parameters": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this. Obviously my answer is incorrect. As soon as OP unaccepts my answer, I will delete it.

Comment: build had a lot of announcements, hard to follow all of those @GauravMantri